# Jest with Enzyme for React Native throwing missing super() call in constructor

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

Having some trouble getting this all setup and working, here is my environment

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS 10.14.2
  Node: 8.9.0
  Yarn: 1.5.1
  npm: 6.4.1
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
  Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4
```

Here is the `jest` config in my `package.json`

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|react-navigation)/"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 80
      }
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./setup-tests.js",
    "setupFiles": ["./setup.js"]
  }
```

In the `setup-tests.js` file I have this setup

```
import 'react-native';
import 'jest-enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';

/**
 * Set up DOM in node.js environment for Enzyme to mount to
 */
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const { window } = jsdom;

function copyProps(src, target) {
  Object.defineProperties(target, {
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(src),
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(target),
  });
}

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js',
};
copyProps(window, global);

/**
 * Set up Enzyme to mount to DOM, simulate events,
 * and inspect the DOM in tests.
 */
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

/**
 * Ignore some expected warnings
 * see: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react.html#snapshot-testing-with-mocks-enzyme-and-react-16
 * see https://github.com/Root-App/react-native-mock-render/issues/6
 */
const originalConsoleError = console.error;
console.error = (message) => {
  if (message.startsWith('Warning:')) {
    return;
  }

  originalConsoleError(message);
};
```

And `setup.js`

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Which I got from this page on the enzyme website

https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/react-native.html

Dependancy versions are

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-jest": "23.6.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
"enzyme": "^3.8.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
"jest": "23.6.0",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.0.1",
"jest-serializer-enzyme": "^1.0.0",
"jsdom": "^13.2.0",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0",
"react-native-mock-render": "^0.1.2",
"react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
```

The specific error I'm getting is

```
***/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/Element.js: missing super() call in constructor

        15 | 
        16 | class Element extends Node.interface {
      > 17 |   constructor() {
           |   ^
        18 |     throw new TypeError("Illegal constructor");
        19 |   }
        20 |
```

I've tried a number of different configurations for this and can't seem to get past this error.

Here is the test file

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {Login} from './index';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';


it('renders correctly', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Login />
  );
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

And I've paired down the file I'm actually testing to try to remove any possible outside library issues

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

export class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

There isn't a difference between the named export and the default export here but normally the default export is connected to redux so I export the named class for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies you show indicate that you are using Babel 6. There's a bug in Babel 6 which causes the kind of issue you describe in your question. It's been reported [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2007) and [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6370).

You should upgrade to Babel 7.

---

In brief, the issue is that prior to the fix in Babel, Babel was doing a static analysis of the code, saw that `super()` was not called and failed the code during static analysis. However, the rule is that `super()` must be called before accessing `this` or returning `this` from the constructor. (If a constructor does not explicitly return a value, it returns `this`.) Since the constructor that you show failing throws, it does not return, and therefore it does not have to call `super()`.

Comment: I was afraid of this, I've tried to get testing working in the latest version of `react-native` which uses babel 7, however, jest then completely breaks and nothing works as it seems they haven't fully supported babel 7. I'll try this again on a fresh `react-native` project with babel 7 and see if I can get it to work I suppose